# How to set the output (the speaker) as the input (the microphone)?

Tags: android, audio-streaming, android-audiomanager

I want to be able to change the audio input (what was the microphone by default), and to change it to what would normally be outputted to the speakers.

My ultimate goal is to be able to, when talking to someone on the phone (either the phone stock app or a third party app like Skype), change the input from the microphone to a simple audio file. So instead of hear my voice from the microphone, the person on the other end of the call would hear an audio file instead.

Comment: You can't. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509441/android-audio-stream-and-microphone/14511380#14511380

Comment: @Michael that really suxs. Do you have any idea how to implement this idea differently?

Comment: Not really. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432521/background-music-for-call/14433414#14433414 for a method that works on some Qualcomm-based devices if you've got root access. But if you want something that will work on a stock Android phone across different platforms I'm afraid you're out of luck.

Comment: Did anyone get the answer for this?